# spacemacs key bindings in plain vanilla evil emacs

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil

As the title suggests, I would like to use spacemacs like keybindings in plain vanilla evil emacs.

The spacemacs key bindings are very intuitive. But the package is too heavy for my low-end laptop. Even simple operations take a long time. So, I am trying to see if there is an intermediate solution.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is probably just to type `C-h m` aka `M-x describe-mode` and see all the stuff that is active (e.g., minor-modes) and start disabling those that you can live without.  Can can also run the profiler and see what functions are the most costly and disable the stuff that is a hog -- `M-x profiler-start`, do some stuff, `M-x profiler-report`, read about it, and then `M-x profiler-stop`.  Also, you may wish to inspect things that get called every command loop by calling `C-h v` or `M-x describe-variable` -- `post-command-hook`, `pre-command-hook`.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the `general` package. It allows to to create “definers” which let you use a prefix key like “space”. From there you just need to add the bindings that you liked from Spacemacs.

Comment: Thanks. It is, indeed, a very useful package. Instead of me reinventing the wheel, is there somewhere that the keybindings mimicking spacemacs are available? I will just import that file.

Comment: I don’t know anywhere official, but there might be a gist out there. Problem is that lots of those keybindings are for packages that you would have to install first.

Comment: Or comment out the ones I don't need :)

Comment: This might get you started. https://gist.github.com/adham90/0d85d023f9d4f1dd28ef#file-spacemacs-keybindings

Comment: Thanks. That was useful. Wish these were actual key-bindings :)

Comment: I hear you. Perhaps if you create them you can post a gist 